# Android/Java - convert escaped control characters to escaped Unicode character

Tags: java, android, unicode, unicode-escapes

In an Android app, I need to convert this...

```
"Hello,\nWorld!"
```

...into this...

```
"Hello,\u000dWorld!"
```

...in order to spit this "converted" string to a remote server through JSON.

How do I accomplish that, preferably WITHOUT the use of anything but the "standard" Java/Android API?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.replace(char, char)`